# I get an error when i test my reducer created with redux

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

**I get this error:**

> ```
>    Reducer "menu" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is 
>    undefined, you must explicitly return
>    the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you
>    dont want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead
>    of undefined.
>
>    5 | import { rootReducer } from "./reducers/rootReducer";
>    6 | 
> >  7 | const reducers = combineReducers({
>      |                  ^
>    8 |   root: rootReducer,
>    9 |   menu: menuReducer,
>   10 |   searcher: searchReducer,
>
>   at node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:378:13
>       at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>   at assertReducerShape (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:371:25)
>   at combineReducers (node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:436:5)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/store.ts:7:18)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/actionCreator.ts:1:1)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/initialState.ts:5:1)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/store/reducers/rootReducer.ts:1:1)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/rootReducer.test.ts:1:1)
>
>   console.error node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:325
>   No reducer provided for key "root"
>
>   Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       0 total Snapshots:   0
>   total Time:        1.175s Ran all test suites related to changed
>   files.
> ```

**when test this reducer (rootReducer.ts):**

```
import { rootInitialState, Reducer, action } from "../initialState";

class RootReducer implements Reducer {
  private initialState: object;

  public constructor(initialState: object) {
    this.initialState = initialState;
  }

  private addNewText = (currentTexts: object, newText: object): object => {
    let newTexts: object = { ...currentTexts };
    newTexts[newText["name"]] = newText["text"];
    return newTexts;
  };

  private switchBodyScroll = (
    payload: "LOCK" | "UNLOCK"
  ): "LOCKED" | "UNLOCKED" => {
    if (payload === "LOCK") {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add("scroll-lock");
      return "LOCKED";
    } else {
      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove("scroll-lock");
      return "UNLOCKED";
    }
  };

  public reduce = (
    state: object = this.initialState,
    action: action
  ): object => {
    if (action.type === "SWITCH_BODY_SCROLL") {
      return {
        ...state,
        bodyScrollState: this.switchBodyScroll(action.payload),
      };
    } else if (action.type === "SWITCH_MINIMAP_MODE") {
      return {
        ...state,
        minimap: {
          ...state["minimap"],
          mode: action.payload.minimapClassList,
          buttonClassList: action.payload.buttonClassList,
        },
      };
    } else if (action.type === "SET_THEMES") {
      return { ...state, themes: [action.payload.items] };
    } else if (action.type === "SET_CURRENT_PAGE") {
      return {
        ...state,
        currentPageId: action.payload.id,
        nextPage: action.payload.next,
        currentPage: [...action.payload.components],
      };
    } else if (action.type === "ADD_NEW_TEXT") {
      return {
        ...state,
        texts: { ...this.addNewText(state["text"], action.payload) },
      };
    } else if (action.type === "SET_PAGE_SEARCHER_VALUE") {
      return { ...state, pageSearcherValue: action.payload };
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  };
}

export const rootReducer = new RootReducer(rootInitialState).reduce;
```

**for example, menuReducer.ts. It contains default state but anyway returns undefined:**

```
import { menuInitialState, Reducer, action } from "../initialState";

class MenuReducer implements Reducer {
  private initialState: object;

  public constructor(initialState: object) {
    this.initialState = initialState;
  }

  public reduce = (
    state: object = this.initialState,
    action: action
  ): object => {
    if (action.type === "SWITCH_MENU_MODE") {
      return { ...state, compactMenuCurtain: action.payload };
    } else {
      return state;
    }
  };
}

export const menuReducer = new MenuReducer(menuInitialState).reduce;
```

**with this test (rootReducer.test.ts):**

```
import { rootReducer } from "../store/reducers/rootReducer";

it("rootReducer should return LOCKED with payload LOCK", () => {
  expect(
    rootReducer(undefined, { type: "SWITCH_BODY_SCROLL", payload: "LOCK" })
  ).toBe("LOCKED");
});
```

**store.ts file looks like this:**

```
import { combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";

import { menuReducer } from "./reducers/menuReducer";
import { searchReducer } from "./reducers/searchReducer";
import { rootReducer } from "./reducers/rootReducer";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  root: rootReducer,
  menu: menuReducer,
  searcher: searchReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(reducers);
```

**I tried to do the same test with other reducers. I get the similar error.**
**Of course i have checked out the menu reducer and tried to test other reducers like that. I get the similar error. Also, each reducer set initial state as default if that was not given. My app work in browser without any errors, I get that only with test. Any imported things are .ts files. Maybe, i just missed something - now i'm learning to work whit jest.**

**I get the same error even i just write a reducer to the console or get the type of this (menuReducer.test.ts):**

```
import { menuReducer } from "../store/reducers/menuReducer";

it("rootReducer should return LOCKED with payload LOCK", () => {
  console.log(menuReducer);
  console.log(typeof menuReducer); // That's a method of class
});
```

Comment: *Of course i have checked out the menu reducer and that one set initial state as default if that was not given* - then please, let others do the same. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary for code-related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've resolve this one. Anyway, this looks strange. If someone has the same stuff he needs a solution. The solution: for some reason i can't just import my reducer and use it as a default method or something like that. Formally it says: "Hey man, i haven't something to give it to reducer, just take an error that cannot help ya.". I initialized my state ( with imported store and call the getState() of it) and this is start working. Code is (rootReducer.test.ts):

```
import { store } from "../store/store";
import { rootReducer } from "../store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { action } from "../store/initialState";

describe("rootReducer test failed", (): void => {
  store.getState(); // Initialize state (looks like this boy allow to use reducers only when you call it)

  it("should return LOCKED with payload LOCK and option SWITCH_BODY_SCROLL", (): void => {
    const switchBodyScrollAction: action = {
      type: "SWITCH_BODY_SCROLL",
      payload: "LOCK",
    };

    const newState: object = rootReducer(undefined, switchBodyScrollAction);

    expect(newState["bodyScrollState"]).toBe("LOCKED");
  });
});
```

**Tests are passed, but i dunno why i can't just use the reducer as a another method;
by the way, other reducers behave the same.**